# How to debug "Could not find module" in Ember.js acceptance tests?

Tags: ember.js

I'm in the process of updating a project to Ember 2.5.0 but stumbled upon an obstacle with running the acceptance tests: after trying to import *moduleForAcceptance* following the documentation for 2.5.0, I'm getting the error

> Could not find module `timelines-front/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance` imported from `timelines-front/tests/acceptance/create-note-test`

The import line is a straight from the documentation:

`import moduleForAcceptance from 'timelines-front/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance';`

I tried creating a new Ember project with one test route and an acceptance test, all generated with CLI, and the import works as expected, so I'm assuming that there's something in my app or test code that is messing up with the `import` statement.

Trying to isolate the case I tried the following after `ember new` without success in reproducing the error:

- Copying *package.json*, *bower.json* and installing.
- Comparing *testem.json* to *testem.js*.
- Checking my Phantomjs version (running 2.1.1)
- Copying *Brocfile.js* and disabling *ember-cli-build.js*

My question is: how can I debug the *include path* and / or find what in the app code is changing it and ruining the `import`?

Answer (score 0):

This is just silly. I forgot to check the files in *tests/helpers* in the structure created by `ember new`, which I realised while writing this question. The *module-for-acceptance.js* and *destroy-app.js* files are there, I just copied them to my project and that error was gone.

I now need to update the acceptance tests code to conform to the newer version.